# How to use mapping to transfer things to an empty array?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass over the function that is inside of the variable inputOne to the empty array of transferHere

This does not seem to be working. How can I map what is inside of inputOne into transferHere, so that everything is transferred over?

```
var transferHere = [];

var inputOne = transferHere.map(function(name) {
return (5 * name) - 20;
});
```

Comment: How does your input look like? What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: `Array.prototype.map()` returns a new array from an existing array, whereas what you want is `Array.prototype.forEach()` which simply iterates over an existing Array performing functions at each step, and returns nothing.

Comment: Madara, I want transferHere to contain everything that is inside of inputOne. I want to have several inputs later on, which I can transfer to the empty array of transferHere.

Comment: I am unable to understand this sentence. "I am trying to pass over the function that is inside of the variable `inputOne` to the empty array of `transferHere`." What do you mean by a "function inside a variable"? What does "pass over" mean"? What do you mean by "pass over to an empty array"? If `inputOne` is your input, show it--what does it contain. If `transferHere` is y our output, show what you want it to be.

Comment: @Dr.Doom2020 how inputOne looks like? is it an object or an array?

Comment: Let me try to simplify this. Everything that is contained inside of the variable **inputOne** I want that to go inside of the **transferHere** array. A simple replication is all I want. Do you understand?

Comment: No, because you've not defined `inputOne`, you've not shown its contents and you've given no information as to the precise output you want. All we can do, so far, is make (apparently) bad guesses as to what you want, what you're doing, why you're doing it and what the result is supposed to be. How, given the lack of information in the question, are we even supposed to offer you a useful answer?

Answer (score 0):

The `map` function iterates over an array of values and generates a new array of values.

For example:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var result = arr1.map(function(val){
    return val + 1;
});

//result would be: [2,3,4]
```

So it seems like you are doing it wrong and your code should be (assuming that 
inputOne is an array):

```
var transferHere= inputOne.map(function(name) {
return (5 * name) - 20;
});
```

**UPDATE:**

From the comment i understand that inputOne is a function and you want to put it's actual content (i.e. as a string) in an array, so here is how:

```
var arr1 = [];
arr1.push(inputOne.toString());
```

Comment: What if I wanted to transfer several inputs, in this very case, inputOne and all of its contents, into an empty array. How would I do that from within the inputOne variable which contains everything?

Comment: See, I don't want to add the inputs from the **array** itself. I want to to be able to replicate the inputs, such as inputOne from within the variable itself, and transfer that to an empty array.

Comment: It's really hard to tell since i don't know the structure of inputOne, it would be very helpful if you post it

Comment: it is just a function. I used map thinking that I could replicate it and put it into transferHere which is an empty array. How do I replicate a function from within the function itself, so that I can send it to an empty array?

Comment: so inputOne is a function, and you want to put it inside an array?

Comment: Correct. But I don't want to use the array to put the function inside of it. I want to use the function, to replicate itself and be sent over into an empty array. Do you get that?

Comment: not really, what is the use case for that? basically, to add a function into an array you just pass a reference to it, like: `arr[0] = somFunction`

Comment: but in this case you are still using the array to hold a function. imagine an empty array arr = []  now, say I have 50 someFunction1, someFunction2 and so on. I don't want to go each time arr[0] = somFunction.   I want to be able to go somFunction === arr[]      so that all of its contents get transferred from **within** the function itself to the empty arr[]

Comment: First of all, you are a bit confused, when doing `somFunction === arr[]` you are actually overriding the value of `somefunction` (the left side always gets the right side value). Secondly, if i understand correctly you want the actual function content inside an array, this means you need to convert it to a string, you can do it like this: `arr1.push(somefunction.toString()) `, but i ask again, what is the use case for this? are you planning on storing these functions in a database/file? or are you planning on executing them later?

Comment: All I am looking for in an inversion of the rule that you have to = an array first for the function to be stored in it.

I want to find an easy way of replicating any function, and inside of that function, being able to send it to an array.  It would save me time. Instead of having to go arr[0] = somFunction arr[1] = somFunction2
I would rather have somFunction(){ //code inside of function transfers to arr[0] from within the function itself.}